# OpenCV + VS2013 + Windows 8.1 x64

Tags: opencv, linker, x86, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit

I have fully followed this tutorial(Installation by using pre-build libraries):
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html

After that I have completed all the steps of this tutorial(The local method):
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html

The **OPENCV_DIR** is set to **Z:\Documents\Work\opencv\build\x64\vc12**,
the **Target Machine** in Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Advanced is set to **/MACHINE:x64.**
When I click Run, I get an error:
**fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'**

When the **OPENCV_DIR** is set to **Z:\Documents\Work\opencv\build\x86\vc12**,
and The **Target Machine** is set to **/MACHINE:x86**,
I get an error:
**fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'**

This seems impossible to me.
Help =C

Comment: Your machine is x64(according to your error), but you are using the x86 files. I think if you use proper ones the problem will be vanished!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal place for specifying the target machine is just what you changed:  **Linker -> Advanced -> Target Machine**.  But OpenCV comes with a little extra gotcha.  In **Linker -> All Options -> Additional Options**, it specifies **/machine:X86**.  When you create a new x64 Platform target from the Win32 Platform, that little bit of configuration comes along for the ride.

So, for your x64 targets, go into **Linker -> All Options -> Additional Options** and remove **/machine:X86**.  Then, the configuration will come from **Linker -> Advanced -> Target Machine**, just as you'd expect.